# Should apps contained in MainApp be required to re-authenticate with AzureAD if user has already authenticated for MainApp with AzureAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebApplication (for ex. WebApp1 at https://test.com/webapp1). WebApp1 requires users to authenticate using AzureAD (TenantId: T1, ClientId: C1). In WebApp1, there are links to access other applications under the same domain

- https://test.com/webapp2
- https://test.com/webapp3

When a user clicks on WebApp2/WebApp3 link from inside WebApp1, should we implement AzureAd Authentication again with a different ClientId for WebApp2 and WebApp3?

Below is the overall picture of the system:
[image]

1. MainWebApp

Answer (score 0):

If they are all different applications and just share a common URL DNS namespace then yes it would be better to use separate client IDs for all three applications. In your Tenant T1, you can create separate service principals (App registration) for WebApp2 and WebApp3 and add the permission in webapp1 for webapp2 and webapp3. And within your application code/api when you are calling "https://test.com/webapp2" try generating a bearer token with the help of [Client-Credential Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and add jwt bearer token to api authorization headers and write an authentication logic in WebApp2/WebApp3 middleware.

Comment: Just wanted to make clear that WebApp1, WebApp2 and WebApp3 are all Web Applications and not WebAPI's. So you are suggesting to create different ClientId's for WebApps1/2/3. But why do we need to add permission in webapp1 for webapp2 and webapp3?

Comment: Also, WebApp1, WebApp2 are MVC applications while While WebApp3 is a Angular application. Can you explain in more detail what do you mean when you say "And within your application code/api when you are calling "https://test.com/webapp2" try generating a bearer token with the help of Client-Credential Flow and add jwt bearer token to api authorization headers and write an authentication logic in WebApp2/WebApp3 middleware."

Comment: I have updated the question to give more details on the actual scenario we are using.